# GHC internals: is there C implementation of the type system?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-construction, ghc

I'm looking into internals of [GHC](https://github.com/ghc/ghc) and I find all the parsing and type system written completely in Haskell. Low-level core of the language is provided by [RTS](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/tree/master/rts). The question is which one of the following is true?

- RTS contains C implementation of the type system and other basic parts of Haskell (I didn't find it, RTS is mainly GC and threading)
- Everything is implemented in Haskell itself. But it seems quite tricky because building GHC already requires GHC.

Could you explain development logic of the compiler? For example [Python](https://github.com/python/cpython) internals provide an opaque implementation of everything in C.

Comment: Types are erased by compilation. The RTS knows nothing about types, it only implements the STG machine (now in eval/apply style) which is an efficient technique for handling closures, thunks, etc. The RTS also implements GC, and some FFI to interface with the C level.

Comment: Apart for the above, I think everything is in Haskell. You can't compile GHC without a previous GHC, just as you can't compile GCC without a previous GCC. I guess very early versions of GHC were bootstrap-pable from C, or from some other Haskell compiler/interpreter which was in turn bootstrap-pable.

Comment: So, everything (for example type inference) is implemented in Haskell. Then STG receives low-level representation of evaluations and just performs it without any type checks, operating with values only?

Comment: Yes, STG does not perform type checks. In many statically-typed programming languages, types are checked at compile time only, and then can be discarded (erased) so that at runtime there is no overhead due to types. In GHC, the static type checker is implemented in Haskell.

Comment: If you really want to see a Haskell type system implemented in C for whatever reason, there is one in Hugs98 (see `src/type.c`).

Comment: Well, one could probably compile an unregistered GHC and use that unregistered GHC to compile GHC to C. But I don't think that's going to be pretty.

Comment: Another resource you may find helpful, but doesn't directly answer your question:   GHC has a ton of complexity for a variety of reasons (historical, experimental, performance, ...) that gets in the way of learning how it works.  Stephen Diehl is blogging about writing a toy implementation of the basics of Haskell, from first principles, with the goal of learning.  [http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, GHC is written almost entirely
in Haskell (plus select GHC extensions) and is intended to be compiled with itself.  In fact, the only program in the world that can compile the GHC compiler is the GHC compiler!  In particular,
parsing and type inference are implemented in Haskell code, and you
won't find a C implementation hidden in there anywhere.

The best source for understanding the internal structure of the
compiler (and what's implemented how) is the [GHC Developer Wiki](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc)
and specifically the "GHC Commentary" link.  If you have a fair bit of spare time, the [video
series](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/AboutVideos) from the
Portland 2006 GHC Hackathon is absolutely fascinating.

Note that the idea of a compiler being written in the language it
compiles is not unusual.  Many compilers are "self-hosting" meaning
that they are written in the language they compile and are intended to
compile themselves.  See, for example, this question on another Stack
Exchange sister site: [Why are self-hosting compilers considered a
rite of passage for new languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263651/why-are-self-hosting-compilers-considered-a-rite-of-passage-for-new-languages), or simply Google for
"self-hosting compiler"

As you say, this is "tricky", because you need a way to get the
process started.  Some approaches are:

- You can write the first compiler in a different language that
  already has a compiler (or write it in assembly language); then,
  once you have a running compiler, you can port it to the same
  language it compiles.  According to [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-language-was-the-first-C-compiler-written-in), the
  first C compiler was written this way.  It was written in "NewB"
  whose compiler was written in "B", a self-hosting compiler that
  had originally been written in assembly and then rewritten in
  itself.
- If the language is popular enough to have another compiler, write
  the compiler in its own language and compile it in phases, first
  with the other compiler, then with itself (as compiled by the
  other compiler), then again with itself (as compiled by itself).
  The last two compiler executables can be compared as a sort of
  massive test that the compiler is correct.  The Gnu C Compiler can
  be compiled this way (and this certainly used to be the standard way to install it from source, using the vendor's [inferior!] C compiler to get started).
- If an interpreter written in another language already exists or is
  easy to write, the compiler can be run by the interpreter to
  compile its own source code, and thereafter the compiled compiler
  can be used to compile itself.  [The first LISP compiler](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-039.pdf) is
  claimed to be the first compiler to bootstrap itself this way.

The bootstrapping process can often be simplified by writing the compiler (at least initially) in a restricted core of the language, even though the compiler itself is capable of compiling the full language.  Then, a sub-par existing compiler or a simplified bootstrapping compiler or interpreter can get the process started.

According to [the Wikipedia entry for GHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler), the original GHC compiler was written in 1989 in Lazy ML, then rewritten in Haskell later the same year.  These days, new versions of GHC with all their shiny new features are compiled on older versions of GHC.

The situation for the Python interpreter is a little different.  An
interpreter can be written in the language it interprets, of course,
and there are many examples in the Lisp world of writing Lisp
interpreters in Lisp (for fun, or in developing a new Lisp dialect, or
because you're [inventing Lisp](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html)), but it can't be interpreters all
the way down, so eventually you'd need either a compiler or an
interpreter implemented in another language.  As a result, most
interpreters aren't self-hosting: the mainstream interpreters for
Python, Ruby, and PHP are written in C.  (Though, PyPy is an alternate
implementation of the Python interpreter that's written in Python,
so...)

Comment: GHC can be built with flags that tell it to create very unoptimized C programs instead of executables. This is how it's bootstrapped on new platforms these days.